# Using diff() to find elapsed time when missing values exist

Tags: r, date

I have data with a grouping variable 'id' and a date column with missing values:

```
id time    date
a   1   2004-01-13
a   2   2004-05-04
a   3       NA
a   4   2007-03-20
a   5       NA
b   1   2004-01-11
b   2   2004-05-04
b   3       NA
b   4   2006-10-10
b   5       NA
c   1   2004-05-23
c   2   2004-10-14
c   3       NA
c   4       NA
c   5       NA
```

Within each 'id', I would like to find the difference between each consecutive pair of dates:

```
id time    date                 difftime
a   1   2004-01-13                 NA
a   2   2004-05-04      (2004-05-04)-(2004-01-13)
a   3       NA                     NA  
a   4   2007-03-20      (2007-03-20)-(2004-05-04)
a   5       NA                     NA
b   1   2004-01-11                 NA
b   2   2004-05-04      (2004-05-04)-(2004-01-11)
b   3       NA                     NA
b   4   2006-10-10      (2006-10-10)-(2004-05-04)
b   5       NA                     NA
c   1   2004-05-23                 NA
c   2   2004-10-14      (2004-10-14)-(2004-05-23)
c   3       NA                     NA
c   4       NA                     NA
c   5       NA                     NA
```

I tried these codes but none of them got what I want.

```
data$difftime <- aggregate(date ~ id, data, diff)

library(data.table)
setDT(data)[ , difftime := diff(data$date), by = id] 
  
diff(data$date)
```

Comment: Builiding on your `data.table` attempt, you may restrict your `diff` calculation to the non-`NA` rows (put `!is.na(date)` in the `i` slot). Also remember that the length of `diff` is one less than the original data so you need to pad with one `NA`: `d[!is.na(date), dif := c(NA, diff(date)), id]`

Comment: I've tried both of your suggestions, thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this `data.table` option could help

```
setDT(df)[
  ,
  difftime := replace(
    rep(NA, .N),
    which(!is.na(date))[-1],
    diff(na.omit(date))
  ),
  id
]
```

or a shorter one (thank @Henrik)

```
setDT(df)[!is.na(date), difftime := c(NA, diff(date)), id]
```

which gives

```
    id time       date difftime
 1:  a    1 2004-01-13       NA
 2:  a    2 2004-05-04      112
 3:  a    3       <NA>       NA
 4:  a    4 2007-03-20     1050
 5:  a    5       <NA>       NA
 6:  b    1 2004-01-11       NA
 7:  b    2 2004-05-04      114
 8:  b    3       <NA>       NA
 9:  b    4 2006-10-10      889
10:  b    5       <NA>       NA
11:  c    1 2004-05-23       NA
12:  c    2 2004-10-14      144
13:  c    3       <NA>       NA
14:  c    4       <NA>       NA
```

Comment: just tried it and got exactly what I need. Thank you so much!

Comment: Or `d[!is.na(date), dif := c(NA, diff(date)), id]`

Comment: @Henrik That's smart! Thanks!